# google analytics javascript security - property ID public

Tags: javascript, html, security, google-analytics

I've read the following question: [Security on Google Analytics and other client-side analytics tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165977/security-on-google-analytics-and-other-client-side-analytics-tools)

But I need an even simpler answer.

Per the google analytics site, I've put the following code in the header of my web site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'propertyID']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'brokersqueeze.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +   '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

While perhaps obvious to most readers here, I realized all this information (like the PropertyID) is available via "inspect element" in the browser.

Have I put the GA snippet properly?  Or is there a way to us GA such that the info is hidden from the public?  It seems like answers for the question above suggest that while the information is public, it's a risk everyone just lives with.  Do I have that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've done it right. That risk exists with every client side analytics tool. If they send spoofed requests to GA, you can try filtering the results in reports. Even if you obfuscate the ID in the javascript code, they can capture the http request and get that ID.